# Sorting a list of dictionaries by key in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries in Python which each contain just one numerical key, and I want to sort them by their keys. 
Example:

```
list = [{.56: 'a'}, {1.0: 'a'}, {.98: 'b'}, {1.0: 'c'}]
```

I want to sort this and return something like this:

```
[{1.0: 'a'}, {1.0: 'c'}, {.98: 'b'}, {.56: 'a'}]
```

In the instance where the key values are the same, I don't care how those are sorted. I've tried using `.sort()` or `.sorted()`, but I'm having trouble figuring out the arguments.

Comment: `sorted(list, reverse=True)` should do the trick

Comment: By the way, `list` is a global function so it's not a good choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simplified version of @dkamins

```
>>> lst = [{.56: 'a'}, {1.0: 'a'}, {.98: 'b'}, {1.0: 'c'}]
>>> sorted(lst, key=max, reverse=True)
[{1.0: 'a'}, {1.0: 'c'}, {0.98: 'b'}, {0.56: 'a'}]
```

recall that `max(d.keys())` returns the same result as `max(d)`

`lambda d: max(d)` just wraps another function around the call to `max` so we can leave that out

Answer (score 2):

This will work in Python 2 and 3:

```
>>> mylist = [{.56: 'a'}, {1.0: 'a'}, {.98: 'b'}, {1.0: 'c'}]

>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: max(d.keys()), reverse=True)
[{1.0: 'a'}, {1.0: 'c'}, {0.98: 'b'}, {0.56: 'a'}]
```

It uses the `sorted`'s `key` argument to sort based on the largest key of each dict, which in this case will just be the first one if you only have one.

The other solution may work, but this is much more straightforward.

P.S. Don't ever name your variables after Python builtins like `list`.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3+, since it throws an error as @Simon mentions. This depends on your dictionaries being singletons:

```
>>> lst = [{.56: 'a'}, {1.0: 'a'}, {.98: 'b'}, {1.0: 'c'}]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d.keys()[0], reverse=True)
[{1.0: 'a'}, {1.0: 'c'}, {0.98: 'b'}, {0.56: 'a'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in Python 3.3, @Hai Vu's comment does not work, because it raises a type error since dict() is not an orderable type. However, the comment suggests an answer if we can convert the dictionary into an orderable type, like a list of tuples for instance:

```
>>>> L = [{.56: 'a'}, {1.0: 'a'}, {.98: 'b'}, {1.0: 'c'}]
>>>> L2 = sorted([list(zip(x.keys(),x.values())) for x in L],reverse=True)
>>>> L2
[[(1.0, 'c')], [(1.0, 'a')], [(0.98, 'b')], [(0.56, 'a')]]
>>>> [{k: v for (k,v) in x} for x in L2]
[{1.0: 'c'}, {1.0: 'a'}, {0.98: 'b'}, {0.56: 'a'}]
```

We start with the given data, assigned to `L` rather than `list` to avoid confusion with the `list` keyword. Then we use a list comprehension  that creates a list of lists of tuples, where each of the sub-lists is the zipped-together keys and values of each dictionary. As lists, those can then be sorted by the `sorted()` function.

Unfortunately, we don't have a list of dictionaries any more so the next step is to convert from a list of lists of tuples back into a list of dictionaries using a dictionary comprehension inside a list comprehension to convert each list of tuples into a dictionary and then return them all together as a list.

Comment: I think an explanation of exactly what you're doing here would make this a splendid answer

Comment: This is a [Schwartzian_transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). This was a common way to do this type of sort before the `key` argument was added